# What is the difference in presentation between hexadecimal ASCII And hexadecimal number

Tags: variables, assembly

I have two questions:

1. What is the difference in presentation between hexadecimal ASCII And hexadecimal number?

I mean that when we say

```
var db 31H
```

How we can find out if we want to say Character a or we want to say number 31H.

2. Why this application goes like this?

   1- a db 4 dup(41h)

   2- b dw 2 dup(4141h)

I thought that this two lines will be run in the same way but in the second line when I want to see the variables they will be 8 8bits and in each one is number 41h.

But it must something wrong because dw is 2 8 bits and we are saying make 2 of 2 of 8 bits and it must be 4 8 bits not 8 8 bits.

Comment: 1) `31h` is not character `a`. But anyway, it only depends on how you use it. 2) It's the same. Memory is just bytes. It does not matter if you have 4 times 0x41 or 2 times `0x4141`.

Comment: Your teacher almost certainly meant to ask you something completely different.  The processor doesn't know anything about ASCII, it only knows about numbers.  But the assembler you use does.  If you meant it to be a letter then you'd use `db 'A'`.  If you meant it to be a number then you'd use `db 41h`.  Makes no difference at all in the final program, but makes a big difference to anybody that reads the code.

Comment: the db/dw lines are not run they dont execute, it is just syntax you use to communicate with the tool to say I want some specific bytes to be placed here in the program/image.  assuming the tool interprets that specific syntax as I would I see that as 4 bytes all of them with the value 41h.  both solutions should produce the same results.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is simple: in a computer's memory, there is no ASCII, no numbers, no images ... there is just bits. `31H` represents the string of bits `00110001`; nothing more, nothing less.

It's only when you do something with those bits (display them to a screen, use them in a mathematical operation, etc) that you interpret it as meaning `1` (which it would in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)), or `a` (in some other character encoding), or `49` (as a decimal number), or a particular shade of blue in your colour palette.